# socket.io confusion with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

server side code:

```
var server = require("http").Server(express);  
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(5000);

io.on('connection', function(client) {

  client.on('order', function(data) {
      io.emit('place_order',data); 
  });
});
```

cilent side code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
 socket.on('place_order', function (data) {alert('data.x')})
```

Somewhere in github I git clone a project and I saw something above. The 3rd line of server side code confused me. Why the author created extra port here? isn't it ok to discard the 3rd line and in the cilent side just connect to the path without port like `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');`? Need explanation for socket.io expert here, I'm confused.

btw this code does work..

Comment: The 3rd line of code was declare because node.js don't often run on port 80. Ex: At [link](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) it shows port 3000.

Comment: @tuananh the 3rd line created another server 5000 for socket and the express app is running 3000. Is that necessary?

Answer (score 0):

> Why the author created extra port here?

You have to start your server on some port and `server.listen(nnn)` is one way to do that.  If you don't start your server, it isn't actually running and you can't ever connect to it.

Servers must be created and then started on a specific port.

In your particular code example, you've chosen to run your server on port 5000 instead of the more common port 80.

> isn't it ok to discard the 3rd line

No.  Without it your server will not be running.

---

If your server is started on port 80, then you don't have to list a port number in the URL since that is the default port number for an `http://` connection.

Comment: look at this page, https://mliu95.github.io/2014/07/13/Creating-an-online-multiplayer-web-game-using-Socketio-and-Quintus-Part1/ on the `Setting up our webserver` part.

Comment: @ThianKianPhin - And look at what on that page?  It has a line `server.listen(80);` for starting the server.  They chose port 80 in that sample.  You can choose the port number for your web server.  The client will, of course, have to connect on whatever port number you choose.

Answer (score 0):

After attaching your `socket.io` to an HTTP server, it needs to start. This how socket works. Thats what the 3rd line does. So, removing it means you are not starting the server itself, and obviously that wouldn't work.

The port is at 5000 which might look unconventional to you, but this is a standard practise to prevent errors if the `PORT 80` is in use, like it often is by other web/internet based applications/servers. But, if that isn't the case feel free to change the port to 80 by replacing the 3rd line as `server.listen(80);`

*For Ref:* if you get the error: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::80` then understand directly that the port wasn't free!!

Comment: but it's express, it runs on 3000 by default, why not use the same port for socket.io too?

Comment: I'm not aware of 3000 being the default port of express. but, if 3000 is free, why not use it if u like?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a socket.io's problem. In a Node.js application you need to specify which port do you want your Node.js runs.

Node.js is a plataform and in the first line you create a server and for that you need to put the port that your server runs.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http